# Images are cut off using bootstrap class img-responsive and jcarousel

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, jcarousel, aspect-ratio

I'm trying to get jcarousel.js and bootstrap to display images. I'm using the [connected carousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/examples/) example, but slightly modified to use bootstrap css.

Here is the following code:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Connected Carousels - jCarousel Examples</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <!-- Example assets -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jcarousel.connected-carousels.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/dist/jquery.jcarousel.min.js?raw=1"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="jcarousel.connected-carousels.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-7">

            <div class="connected-carousels">
                <div class="stage">
                    <div class="carousel carousel-stage">
                        <ul>
                            <li><img class="img-responsive" src="http://cdn.wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/digital-wallpaper-3.jpg" width="600" height="400" alt=""></li>
                            <li><img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.susansolovic.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/instagram-logo-md-300x300.png" width="600" height="400" alt=""></li>
                            <li><img class="img-responsive" src="http://graphics8.nytimes.com/images/2014/03/13/learning/VTS03-17-14LN/VTS03-17-14LN-tmagArticle.jpg" width="600" height="400" alt=""></li>
                            <li><img class="img-responsive" src="http://cdn.themetapicture.com/media/cute-family-picture-portrait-penguin.jpg" width="600" height="400" alt=""></li>
                            <li><img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.petmountain.com/photos/product/giant/114420S519156/aquarium-power-filters/cascade-power-filter-for-aquariums.jpg" width="600" height="400" alt=""></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <p class="photo-credits">
                        Photos by <a href="http://www.mw-fotografie.de">Marc Wiegelmann</a>
                    </p>
                    <a href="#" class="prev prev-stage"><span>&lsaquo;</span></a>
                    <a href="#" class="next next-stage"><span>&rsaquo;</span></a>
                </div>

                <div class="navigation">
                    <a href="#" class="prev prev-navigation">&lsaquo;</a>
                    <a href="#" class="next next-navigation">&rsaquo;</a>
                    <div class="carousel carousel-navigation">
                        <ul>
                            <li><img src="http://cdn.wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/digital-wallpaper-3.jpg" width="50" height="50" alt=""></li>
                            <li><img src="http://www.susansolovic.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/instagram-logo-md-300x300.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></li>
                            <li><img src="http://graphics8.nytimes.com/images/2014/03/13/learning/VTS03-17-14LN/VTS03-17-14LN-tmagArticle.jpg" width="50" height="50" alt=""></li>
                            <li><img src="http://cdn.themetapicture.com/media/cute-family-picture-portrait-penguin.jpg" width="50" height="50" alt=""></li>
                            <li><img src="http://www.petmountain.com/photos/product/giant/114420S519156/aquarium-power-filters/cascade-power-filter-for-aquariums.jpg" width="50" height="50" alt=""></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                <h3> Hello World </h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

You can get `jcarousel.connected-carousels.css` and `jcarousel.connected-carousels.js` on [jcarousel github](https://github.com/jsor/jcarousel/tree/master/examples/connected-carousels).

The images were pulled randomly off the net, but all the images have different sizes, and only the stage images have the class `img-responsive`. However, when the page is viewed, all the images seem to be cut off in some way:

- The first image seems fine, although I'm not sure because of all the problems with the other images.
- The second image shows the camera cut off at the bottom lens
- The third image shows the humanoid's feet slightly cut off
- The fourth and fifth images have both been severely cut off.

Without `img-responsive`, the images are either stretched or cut off in some way.

**How do I preserve the image ratios and have them fit inside the stage div?**

Answer (score 0):

Target the div id and/or class and use a style like this

```
.somediv img{
    width:100%;
}
```

You could run into overflow issues but nothing that can't be fixed.